# how view asp web pages in c# windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, integration, localhost

I am developing an windows application and I need to load some local asp .net web pages.
how could I do this ?actually I need a local server application that works with my application then i can run asp .net web pages in my windows application.
tanks for your help
can I use asp .net development server as a component to work with my application?

Comment: If you need a "local server application" for ASP.Net, you will need IIS. But please consider the security implications if you are using this for a desktop application.

Comment: my application have no installation and my user don't know how to install IIS service.I need an stand alone local host like telerik example demo for web controls that is my purpose

Comment: I don't understand, if your app is just going to display your own web pages, why not just make those windows in your app?   Do you have legacy ASP.NET code you need to integrate into your app and don't want to rewrite it?  Do you need to know both how to display those pages in a windows app and how to serve them yourself?

Comment: yes,my app just display my own web pages.can I add an ASP.net handler to my win application to solve this?if yes how it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) is a standalone instance of IIS that can be deployed to users (there's a .MSI).

IIS Express is, according to the linked page, a wrapper round "hostable web core" - which sounds like it might be an even better match to your needs - but I've not investigated that at all so can't comment on what's involved in using it.

---

As an aside, I'd have to agree that its a slightly strange requirement - you might want to clarify that.

Comment: can IIS Express installed in silent?

Comment: +1 for correct way to achieve this through `IIS Express`.. i was also looking to write here through `iis`.